# Pretty lame reviews.. Why do people want this?

Tags: knowledge

Browsing an online store, you see this product. The reviews are pretty low, but it seems many people want it. What is it ?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The product is:

> **The men's football World Cup**

Each of the names is:

> The first name of a famous/prominent current international footballer:
>
>  Paul **Pogba** (France);
>  Harry **Kane** (England);
>  Thomas **Müller** (Germany);
>  Mohamed **Salah** (Egypt);
>  Lionel **Messi** (Argentina).

And the 'star ratings' are *not* ratings at all! They are:

> The number of times their national teams have won the trophy:
>
>  France 2 (1998 & 2018);
>  England 1 (1966);
>  Germany (including triumphs as West Germany) 4 (1954, 1974, 1990 & 2014);
>  Egypt 0 (never);
>  Argentina 2 (1978 & 1986).

Where else might you see these 'star ratings'?

> Above the national team badge on their football kits - each time a team is victorious they are entitled to add another star to their crest.

Comment: Now I wonder, what exactly is that blurred out text below the image?

Comment: Looks like the 4th word is Trophy

Comment: "Soccer World Cup Trophy : Guaranteed 100% Authentic".

Comment: Also, the picture is a very skilfully blurred out version of the actual trophy.

Answer (score 5):

The product is

> 1 Layered Toilet Paper

The reviews are bad because

> it tears easily

Everyone wants it because

> there is a shortage of toilet paper due to COVID19

The product exists because

> a toilet paper company changed their production from 3 or 4 layers to 1 in order to keep up with the increasing demand

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer, based off of the question itself? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Comment: Would the Thomas who gave it four stars be [this chap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Crapper)?

Comment: @Deusovi The answer was not meant to be taken completely serious. Maybe I should have made that clearer. The connection to the question is that it is something that toilet is in high demand (many people want it) for seemingly irrational reasons. Regarding the actual answer I am stumped because it seems like the only thing that could uniquely specify it are the names given in the review section.

Comment: Funny answer and comment, but this has nothing to do with the current pandemic :)

Comment: Joke answers are usually frowned upon, but this one is really good IMO. Have my upvote.